# How to print hex String from U256 struct from ethers library?

Tags: rust, hex, byte

I am using Rust and crate `ethers`
By reading logs from EVM chains I am working with transaction hashes and addresses. These are expressed as `U256` or `H160` objects. Consider the example code below:

```
use ethers::prelude::{Log};
use ethers::types::{Address, H160, H256, U256};

async fn print_log_details(&self, log: &Log) {
    let block_number = log.block_number.unwrap();
    let from: H160 = Address::from(log.topics[1]);
    let to: H160 = Address::from(log.topics[2]);
    let token_id: U256 = U256::decode(log.topics[3]).unwrap();
    let transaction_hash: H256 = log.transaction_hash.unwrap();

    dbg!(log.clone());
    println!(
        "block_number = {}, from = {}, to = {}, tokenId = {}, transactionHash = {}",
        block_number, from, to, token_id, transaction_hash
    );
}
```

generates out put like this:

```
[src/main.rs:54] log.clone() = Log {
address: 0x7ea3cca10668b8346aec0bf1844a49e995527c8b,
topics: [
    0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef,
    0x000000000000000000000000603503a11a37acb6e9d8ff2423c29d135255df49,
    0x0000000000000000000000004a6ead6446265533b6b5257bbfb450e1cdfae5ec,
    0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000bf5,
],
data: Bytes(0x),
block_hash: Some(
    0xd6da518349a24d4414163bd4b51678c7b8629bd8e0fa9b59e57fcbe2a8e93a98,
),
block_number: Some(
    13032069,
),
transaction_hash: Some(
    0xa520f3d255140abeb8cec33764a3a1c0ccbcf9496a934e25f1bbf004667cbddf,
),
transaction_index: Some(
    383,
),
log_index: Some(
    321,
),
transaction_log_index: None,
log_type: None,
removed: Some(
    false,
),
}

block_number = 13032069, from = 0x6035…df49, to = 0x4a6e…e5ec, tokenId = 3061, transactionHash = 0xa520…bddf
```

I would like to see the `from`, `to`, and `transaction` in println in full hex form, not in this truncated form. How can I do that? It seems that `Display` trait on these structs is truncating the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both types `U256` and `H160` support [`UpperHex`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/trait.UpperHex.html) and [`LowerHex`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/trait.LowerHex.html) formatting. Read more about formatting in Rust here: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/index.html#formatting-parameters. You can use `X` or `x` in the formatting string (plus padding and `0x` as prefix) to achieve printing the full type out of the box:

```rust
/*
[dependencies]
ethers = "*"
*/
use ethers::types::{U256, H160};

fn main() {
    let u256 = U256::MAX;
    let h160 = H160::repeat_byte(0x0F);

    println!("{u256:#032X}");
    println!("{u256:#032x}");

    println!("{h160:#020X}");
    println!("{h160:#020x}");
}
```

**Stdout:**

```
0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
0x0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F
0x0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f
```

[Rustexplorer.](https://www.rustexplorer.com/b#%2F*%0A%5Bdependencies%5D%0Aethers%20%3D%20%22*%22%0A*%2F%0Ause%20ethers%3A%3Atypes%3A%3A%7BU256%2C%20H160%7D%3B%0A%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20u256%20%3D%20U256%3A%3AMAX%3B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20h160%20%3D%20H160%3A%3Arepeat_byte(0x0F)%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20println!(%22%7Bu256%3A%23032X%7D%22)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20println!(%22%7Bu256%3A%23032x%7D%22)%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20println!(%22%7Bh160%3A%23020X%7D%22)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20println!(%22%7Bh160%3A%23020x%7D%22)%3B%0A%7D)